# SQL XML Namespace Issues

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, namespaces

Having an issue importing this namespace through on SQL Server.

```
<MISRoot xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   
         xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/IGUK.Evolution.FieldToolLite.Lib.MIS">
```

I have tried single quotes double quotes but i can't seem to figure it.

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/IGUK.Evolution.FieldToolLite.Lib.MIS')
INSERT tbl_MI_XML_IMPORT 
    ([ProductId], [Ancillaries])
SELECT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `xmlns:i` namespace is usually not used - try this approach instead:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/IGUK.Evolution.FieldToolLite.Lib.MIS')
INSERT tbl_MI_XML_IMPORT 
    ([ProductId], [Ancillaries])
SELECT
```